# NiFi: Reference FlowFile content in ExecuteSQL Processor

Tags: sql, apache-nifi

Is it possible to reference a FlowFile's content in a subsequent `ExecuteSQL` processor?

For example:

- I'm using `GenerateTableFetch` and `ExecuteSQL` to poll a database table.
- Next, I use `QueryRecord` to transform the result -- specifically, use `MAX()` and `GROUP BY` operations, because I can't use this operators with the `GenerateTableFetch` processor.

.

```
SELECT
    hu_id
    ,wh_id
    ,MAX(audit_timestamp) AS "newest_timestamp"
FROM FLOWFILE
GROUP BY
    hu_id
    ,wh_id
```

- I would love to be able to then use another ExecuteSQL to do something like:

.

```
SELECT
    FLOWFILE.hu_id
    ,FLOWFILE.wh_id
    ,FLOWFILE.newest_timestamp
    ,hum.status
    ,hum.location_id
FROM FLOWFILE
INNER JOIN AAD.dbo.t_hu_master hum ON
    FLOWFILE.hu_id = hum.hu_id
    AND FLOWFILE.wh_id = hum.wh_id
```

... effectively referencing the Avro FlowFile content to perform a multi-join.

**If this isn't possible, then is there an elegant workaround?**  So far, the only solution I can come up with is ...

1. `SplitAvro`
2. `ConvertAvroToJSON`
3. `EvaluateJSONPath`
4. `ReplaceText` (to create a bunch of individual SQL SELECT statements with the `wh_id` and `hu_id`), and then ...
5. `ExecuteSQL`

Any thoughts or insights are appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

In the upcoming 1.10.0 release, you'll be able to do a lookup from a database using LookupRecord and the new DatabaseRecordLookupService (see [NIFI-6082](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-6082)), this effectively does a join. In the meantime I think you'll need something like what you have, or a scripted processor (see ExecuteGroovyScript's Additional Details page) to do the lookup yourself.

Comment: Thanks, @mattyb -- I won't accept this answer so that, when available, we can point to the 1.10.0 release notes!